# How do I compare one string to many other strings?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two list of names, and find the names who are on both lists. However the lists are not in the same order and of different lengths.

I tried a code compare the first name of the first list ("A1") to the first one in the other list ("B1"), and then compare it to the second ("B3") and so on until it matches. If it matches it writes "Match" on the third column, or "Not a match" if there is no match

```vb
Sub CompareTest()
    Dim iComp As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim str1 As string, str2 As string

    For i = 1 to 20
        str1 = ("A" & i)

        For j = 1 to 20
            str2 = ("B" & j)
            iComp = StrComp(str1, str2, vbTextCompare)

            Select Case iComp
            Case 0
                Range ("C" & i) = "Match"
            Case 1
                Range ("C" & i) = "Match"
            End Select

            If Range ("C" & i) = "Match" Then Exit For
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Right now, the code writes "Not a match" in every cell from 1 to 20 even though there are matches, and I'm not sure what's not working.

Comment: Do you need to do this in VBA? It could be done with formulas (`MATCH`)

Comment: You are comparing addresses. "A1" to "B1" etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are comparing the strings `"An"` and `"Bn"` and not the contents of the address.  But even if you correct that, you are still writing "Match" if `str1` is equal to **or greater than** `str2`.  Probably not what you want.

You can probably do something like:

```
C1:  =IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1),"Match","Not a Match")
```

or, in code

```
Option Explicit
Sub matcher()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim C As Range, rSearch As Range, rLookup As Range

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")
With WS
    Set rLookup = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    .Columns(3).Clear
End With


For Each C In rLookup
    If rSearch.Find(what:=C, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
        C.Offset(0, 2) = "No Match"
    Else
        C.Offset(0, 2) = "Match"
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```